# How can I create directories using subversion version numbers in gnu make?

Tags: svn, makefile, gnu

Thanks to 'Beta' my solution:

```
RLS_DIRECTORY = $(shell svnversion -cn | sed 's/:/-/')
SVN_VERSION   = $(shell svnversion -cn | sed -r 's/.+://')
RELEASE_NOTES = $(RLS_DIRECTORY:=/release-notes-$(SVN_VERSION:=.txt))

-include svn-version.mk

SVN_OLD_VERSION ?= 0

.PHONY = all zip release

release: $(RELEASE_NOTES)

$(RLS_DIRECTORY):
    mkdir -p $@

$(RELEASE_NOTES): $(RLS_DIRECTORY)
    @echo 'Creating release notes ($@)'
    @svn log -r $(SVN_OLD_VERSION):HEAD -v > $@ \
      && echo "SVN_OLD_VERSION ?= `svnversion -c | sed -r 's/.+://'`" \
       > svn-version.mk
```

Which in nutshell, when I ask `make` to do so (`# make release`) creates a version specific directory and then dumps the log data to a version specific log file since the last time the target was invoked.  Persistent data (SVN_OLD_VERSION) is stored in svn-version.mk, which is conditionally included.

---

Original post:

*Amongst other subversion specific targets in my project 'make' file (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332122/delaying-or-repeating-a-prerequisite-in-gnu-make/1487460#1487460)) I've got some targets that I trying to add for the purposes of creating a log files from the last time the 'release' ' target was invoked.  So far:*

```
SVN_VERSION ?= 0
-include svn-version.mk

RLS_DIR = `svnversion -cn | sed 's/://'`

.PHONY = $(RLS_DIR) notes release

notes: $(RLS_DIR)\notes.txt
release: notes

svn-version.mk:
    @echo 'Generating $@'
    @echo "SVN_VERSION ?= `svnversion -c | sed -r 's/.+://'`" > $@

$(RLS_DIR):
    mkdir $@

$(RLS_DIR)\notes.txt: $(RLS_DIR)
    svn log -r $(SVN_VERSION):HEAD > $@
```

*But I'm trying to figure out 2 things:*

*1. **How can I create a directory based on the `svnversion` output?** The above gives me an error "*** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop."  svnversion produces "nnnn:mmmm" and I'd like to create a directory "nnnn-mmmm".)*

*2. **How can I get the include file "svn-version.mk" only to rebuild when the 'release' target is executed?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear -- and I am not familiar with subversion -- but I can make an educated guess:

1. Use "shell", not backticks, to set RLS_DIR:

   ```
   RLS_DIR = $(shell svnversion -cn | sed 's/:/-/')
   ```

   This is a strange way to arrange things. Unless you need svn-version.mk for some other purpose, I'd suggest this:

   ```
   release: SVN_VERSION ?= $(shell svnversion -c | sed -r 's/.+://')
   ```

**EDIT:**
I'm still not entirely clear on what you're trying to do with svn-version.mk, but svn-version.mk can be a prerequisite of "release". If svn-version.mk depends on log.txt then log.txt can be its prerequisite, otherwise you will have a hard time preventing svn-version.mk from being remade every time (you probably shouldn't include it at all).

Comment: Full points for '1.'.  I would like the contents of svn-version.mk to be persistent: its used as a reference point since the last version the log output was created. i.e. take log messages between the last time run and now:  "svn -log $(SVN_VERSION):HEAD > log.txt; ~redo svn-version.mk~"

Comment: I'm not going for a POSIX make; and I'm taking advantage of the conditional include provided by GNU make.  In fact, I didn't create a specific rule for 'svn-version.mk, instead it's a side-affect/additional output of the 'release' target itself.  If I made svn-version.mk a prerequisite then I would get the behaviour you describe.  I hope my 'solution' above illuminates what I was trying to do.